# How to use System.IO.Unsafe together with TVars?

Tags: haskell

I would like to call a UDP send function within an STM transaction so that I can avoid code like below where m' is read (and could be updated by an other thread) before the values are eventually sent & where two consecutive where clauses make me look quite "helpless".

```
sendRecv s newmsgs q m = do
     m' <- atomically $ readTVar m
     time <- getPOSIXTime
     result <- appendMsg newmsgs key m
     when (result > 0) (atomically $ do 
                           mT <- readTVar m
                           qT <- readTVar q
                           --let Just messages = Map.lookup key mT in sendq s (B.pack $ unwords messages) "192.168.1.1" 4711 
                           let mT' = Map.delete key mT
                               qT' = PSQ.delete key qT
                           writeTVar q (PSQ.insert key time qT')
                           writeTVar m (Map.insert key [newmsgs] mT'))
     when (result > 0) (let Just messages = Map.lookup key m' in sendq s (B.pack $ unwords messages) "192.168.1.1" 4711) 

sendq :: Socket -> B.ByteString -> String -> PortNumber -> IO ()
sendq s datastring host port = do
      hostAddr <- inet_addr host
      sendAllTo s datastring (SockAddrInet port hostAddr)
      return ()
```

I thought that by invoking TVars with `newTVarIO` and using `import System.IO.Unsafe` I could eventually use `unsafePerformIO` somewhere and call my sendq function (that returns `IO()` ) from within the transaction.

However, I do not find where this "somewhere" is? Is it at the creation of the TVar? Is it instead of `atomically $ do`? Do I understand the sense an applicability of unsafePerformIO wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

IO cannot be done from inside an STM block, because general IO cannot be undone. If you want to do some IO, you must schedule it in the STM block, but do it outside. For example:

```
foo tvar = do
    scheduledAction <- atomically $ do
        v <- readTVar tvar
        when v retry
        return (sendSomethingOnASocket "okay, we're done here")
    scheduledAction
```

Comment: Is there any possibility to prioritize the transactions of thread a over thread b? E.g. If thread a has constantly transactions and thread b more infrequently, could b sort of "interrupt" a? I tried an MVar where b could prevent a from running for a while. But was not to elegant.

Comment: @JFritsch MVars and STM don't really mix. I don't know of a way to ask for one thread to be prioritized over another. However, if you're not livelocking, both threads should eventually make progress.

Comment: I do not understand the 'when v retry'. Isn't it that a failed transaction is retried again transparently without me taking care for it in the code?

Comment: @JFritsch I just needed some random STM code to flesh the example out. To answer your direct question, though: yes, failed transactions are retried again transparently; but one way to fail is to explicitly fail (by calling `retry`). For example, in a banking system, you might explicitly call `retry` in a withdrawal transaction when you notice that the amount they want to withdraw exceeds the balance in the account.

Comment: This works so wonderful! Thanks again. Thanks also to @hammar who recently explained me what an action is.

Answer (score 4):

If you *really* need to do IO within a transaction, there's [`unsafeIOToSTM :: IO a -> STM a`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/GHC-Conc-Sync.html#v%3aunsafeIOToSTM), however you should make sure to read the documentation first, as there are several gotchas to be aware of. In particular, the IO action may be run several times if the transaction has to be retried.

That said, I don't think that is appropriate in this case, and you should probably refactor your code so that the message is sent outside the transaction.